# How to pass user data within app (Flutter)

Tags: database, flutter

I am developing an app where there are different types of accounts. There are administrators and students. Based on which account type you have you have different abilities within the app, admin can post announcements and students cannot etc. How do I pass the type of account that the user has after they login to all of the widgets/files in my project?

I am developing this app using flutter.

Comment: You can use Firebase Auth. Then you can save user role to Firestore Database.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a StreamController, however i would rather use a

```
 var loggedUserType = BehaviorSubject<UserType?>.seeded(null);
```

then could simply access the userType using a stream builder, or you could also call the value of the stream itself if you need to access from functions or from the init state in your child widgets

```
UserType? type = loggedUserType.value
```

you may place this stream at the root of your app of in a specific class that has all your app streams